# is there any free software which can be used to generate .exe format Ebook?

Tags: ebook, chm

Please advice a good software to generate `.exe` format Ebook  /(or chm format)

Comment: why down vote ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what's the source document, neither the platform on which you're working

Comment: I need a .exe format ebook, which generate from HTML page. certainly is windows

Answer (score 5):

[CHMProcessor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chmprocessor/) is the best free help document compiler I've found. Convert to CHM or Java help file from HTML or Microsoft Word format.